# I get Notepad++ v6.5.1 - unknown exception error

Tags: windows-7, windows, notepad++

Today I am running into a problem with Notepad++. Any time I try to run it ( or just open a txt file ) I get the "unknown exception" error. Error window title also says Exception On WM_CRE... , but that's all, it won't maximize. I had no problems with it until today no matter what version or my OS. I can also add I tried reinstalling, and also installing earlier version ( v6.5 ) and it was same.

I run Win 7 x64 and latest version of Notepad available here: 
http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.5.1.html 
I don't really believe it's related, but anyway, today my Mozilla Firefox also started crashing upon opening downloaded files or clicking a link to "browse for a file" window. Thank you, JC

Comment: Do you have any extensions to Notepad++ installed?

Comment: Not that I knew of, just the installation from the installer that you get on the NP++ website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this error is related to plugins malfunctions, Try reinstalling your plugins, just open the plugin manager, select all your plugins and click on "reinstall" button.

Some recommend removing files such as HTMLPreview.dll or certificates.xml for FTP plugin. I even tried reinstalling notepadd++ without success. so do not guess and just reinstall them all :)